# Computing the partition function via one of the three methods

Tags: pr.probability, it.information-theory, statistical-physics

I am trying to compute the averaged partition function for some system (with very large $N$) and I reach this point:
\begin{equation}
        \left < Z\right > =\int \prod_i^N \left (\frac{\mathrm{d}x_i}{\sqrt{2\pi/i}} \right )\exp{\left \{-\frac{i}{2}\sum_i^N\lambda_\epsilon x_i^2  - \frac{\left ( \sum_{i}^Nx_i^2\right ) ^2}{4N}    \right\} }
\end{equation}
I simply have to evaluate the integral, but the annoying part is to first correctly uncouple the $x_i$ and $x_j$ which I cannot seem to do correctly. One way is to use the method of gaussian linearisation, which consists in saying that:
\begin{equation}
\exp{\left \{ \frac{\left ( \sum_{i}^Nx_i^2\right ) ^2}{4N}    \right\} }=\exp{\{\frac{b^2}{4a}\}}=\int\sqrt\frac{a}{\pi}\exp\{-am^2+bm\}\mathrm{d}m
\end{equation}
Here is my working out:
\begin{equation}
        \left < Z\right >_M =\int \prod_i \left (\frac{\mathrm{d}x_i}{\sqrt{2\pi/i}} \right )\exp{\left \{-\frac{i}{2}\sum_i\lambda_\epsilon x_i^2  - \frac{\left ( \sum_{i}x_i^2\right ) ^2}{4N}    \right\} }
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
        \left < Z \right >_M =\int_m \int \prod_i \left (\frac{\mathrm{d}x_i}{\sqrt{2\pi/i}} \right )C_1\exp{\left \{-\frac{i}{2}\sum_i\lambda_\epsilon x_i^2  +i  \sum_{i}x_i^2m - Nm^2   \right\}}\mathrm{d}m 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
        \left < Z\right >_M =\int_m C_1 \prod_i \left (\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x_i}{\sqrt{2\pi/i}} \exp{\left \{-\frac{i}{2}\lambda_\epsilon x_i^2  +i  x_i^2m \right\} }\right )  \exp{\left \{ - Nm^2   \right\}}\mathrm{d}m 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
        \left < Z\right >_M =C_1\int_m  \prod_i \left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_\epsilon - 2m}} \right )  \exp{\left \{ - Nm^2   \right\}}\mathrm{d}m 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
        \left < Z\right >_M =C_1\int_m   \exp{\left \{ N(-m^2 -\frac{1}{2}\ln(\lambda_\epsilon - 2m) \right\}}\mathrm{d}m 
\end{equation}
Unfortunately this last integral cannot be computed via Laplace method, and anyway does not make sense with the results I am supposed to recover. 
I tried different methods, notably enforcing a delta function in order to uncouple the variables but it gets really messy. Any hint or advice about where it goes wrong?

Thanks a lot! Any input is more than welcome.

Comment: your calculation seems correct, and the final integral can be evaluated in terms of a hypergeometric function (you will need to give $\lambda$ an infinitesimal imaginary part)

Comment: minor quip: please don't use $i$ for both the imaginary unit as well as an index of summation or products!